# Different output child and parent for hierarchy list

Tags: c#, list, hierarchy, listitem

I have table hierarchy list like this:

```
ID  ParentID
1   0
2   7
3   1
4   5
5   1
6   2
7   1
8   6
9   0
10  9
```

I want to the output to **listTtem** if child lvl1 add `|___` then +value, if child lvl 2 add `<space>` then `|___` then +value

Output:

```
1 
|___ 3
|___ 5
     |___ 4
|___ 7 
     |___ 2 
          |___ 6 
               |___ 8
     |___ 11
9
|___ 10
```

What i'm done:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<MyClass> Children = new List<MyClass>();
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// GET: Reporting
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<MyClass> ofitems = new List<MyClass>();
    var dbs = db.ORG_FUNCTION.Select(pk => new { pk.FUNCTION_ID, pk.FUNCTION_PARENT_ID, pk.NAME });
    foreach (var s in dbs)
    {
        ofitems.Add(new MyClass { ID = s.FUNCTION_ID.ToString(), ParentID = s.FUNCTION_PARENT_ID.ToString(), Name = s.NAME });
    }
    Action<MyClass> SetChildren = null;
    SetChildren = parent =>
    {
        parent.Children = ofitems
            .Where(childItem => childItem.ParentID == parent.ID)
            .ToList();
        //Recursively call the SetChildren method for each child.
        parent.Children
            .ForEach(SetChildren);
    };
   //ViewBag.list = ????;
    return View();
}
```

But It's just show the same output. How to get different output by parent child

Comment: Not an answer, but suggestion: your `SetChildren` is quadratic (`O(n*n)`), while it can be linear (`O(n)`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to recursively walk through your tree to output it correctly.
Your algorithm does use recursion, but it just fills `Children` property which can be even done linearly:

```
var byNodeId = ofitems.ToDictionary(x => x.ID, x => x);
foreach (var node in ofitems)
{
    // add current node to its parent's Children
    byNodeId[node.ParentID].Children.Add(node); 
}
```

Is is important because your algorithm needs `O(n*n)` operations to fill `Children` which is `n` times worse than it can be.

Even after filling `Children` in, you still need to [DFS (Depth-First Search)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) through your tree - it can either be done with `Queue` or recursion.
That's how recursion way may look like:

```
public static class TreeFormatter
{
    private static string FormatTreeItem(MyClass item, int depth)
    {
        if (depth == 0) 
            return $"{item.ID}"; // you can use Name in return

        return $"{new string(' ', (depth - 1) * 8)}|___ {item.ID}"; // 8 spaces per level       
    }

    private static void FormatSubtree(StringBuilder sb, List<MyClass> items, string current, int depth)
    {
        foreach (var child in items.Where(x => x.ParentID == current)) // perhaps .OrderBy?
        {
            sb.AppendLine(FormatTreeItem(child, depth));
            FormatSubtree(sb, items, child.ID, depth + 1);
        }
    }

    public static string Format(List<MyClass> items)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        FormatSubtree(sb, items, "0", 0); // "0" = root
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: LINQPad demo]

And your controller can look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<MyClass> ofitems = _repository.GetMyClasses(); // contains db access logic

    // This actually can be in repository too:
    var byNodeId = ofitems.ToDictionary(x => x.ID, x => x);
    foreach (var node in ofitems)
    {
        // add current node to its parent's Children
        byNodeId[node.ParentID].Children.Add(node); 
    }

    ViewBag.ListText = TreeFormatter.Format(ofitems); 
    return View();
}
```

There are many places in this code where you can improve it, it just shows the idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to build your `MyClass` tree.

Try this:

```
ILookup<int, int> lookup = source.ToLookup(x => x.ParentID, x => x.ID);
Func<int, List<MyClass>> build = null;
build = pid =>
    lookup[pid]
        .Select(id => new MyClass()
        {
            Children = build(id),
            ID = id,
            ParentID = pid
        })
        .ToList();

List<MyClass> ofitems = build(0);
```

If you start with this data:

```
var source = new[]
{
    new { ID = 1, ParentID = 0 },
    new { ID = 2, ParentID = 7 },
    new { ID = 3, ParentID = 1 },
    new { ID = 4, ParentID = 5 },
    new { ID = 5, ParentID = 1 },
    new { ID = 6, ParentID = 2 },
    new { ID = 7, ParentID = 1 },
    new { ID = 8, ParentID = 6 },
    new { ID = 9, ParentID = 0 },
    new { ID = 10, ParentID = 9 },
};
```

Then you get this result:

[image: result]

I did change your definition of `MyClass` to use `int` as the ID type rather than string, but it works for strings too.

The output is fairly easy too.

Try this:

```
string divider = "|___";
Func<IEnumerable<MyClass>, int, IEnumerable<string>> output = null;
output = (items, n) =>
    items
        .SelectMany(item =>
            new []
            {
                "".PadLeft(
                    divider.Length * (n - 1 > 0 ? n - 1 : 0))
                    + (n > 0 ? divider : "")
                    + item.ID
            }.Concat(output(item.Children, n + 1)));
```

Then with `output(ofitems, 0)` I get this:

```
1 
|___3 
|___5 
    |___4 
|___7 
    |___2 
        |___6 
            |___8 
9 
|___10
```